# Reading in variables from a file to use in a bash script strips out \

Tags: shell-script, sed, regular-expression

So I am loading in a properties file to define some variables. In this example imagine it is a string `mark!slash\ending\` called `INPUT`.

`INPUT` is declared by loading in the properties file using:

```
. ./properties
```

where

```
INPUT=mark!slash\ending\
```

I need the final output to be a script run through SED of the form `s!@output@!$INPUT!g` such that when executed, `@output@` is replaced in another file with the input from the properties file defined by the user (the variable, in this case, is `INPUT`). We are using `!` as the delimiter in SED so this character will need to be escaped (as well as any `\`) before added to the SED template file.

If I try

```
echo SAFE_INPUT=$(printf '%s\n' 'mark!slash\ending\' | sed 's:[\!]:\\&:g')
```

I get the expected output

```
mark\!slash\\ending\\
```

If, however, I try

```
SAFE_INPUT=$(printf '%s\n' "${INPUT}" | sed 's:[\!]:\\&:g')
```

I get

```
mark\!slashending
```

I am assuming it is something to do with my declaration of string vs a variable but I am at a loss as to the difference and how to solve the issue right now.

Edit:
On further testing `INPUT` as read using

```
. ./properties
```

is printed as

```
mark!slashending
```

So this is not an issue with SED but with reading in the property file.

Comment: how you are declaring `INPUT`?

Comment: We really can't help if you don't show us how you assign a value to `INPUT`. The command you show works perfectly well if you just use `INPUT='mark!slash\ending\'`.

Comment: Edited to show how INPUT is loaded in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when you set variable `INPUT` in file `properties` like shown in the question

```
INPUT=mark!slash\ending\
```

and source it as a shell script.

The first `\e` is replaced by the shell with `e` and the `\` at the end of the line will either be removed if there is some whitespace following it, otherwise it denotes that the line is continied in the next line. So the value of `INPUT` will already be modified.

You either have to define your input with quotes

```
INPUT='mark!slash\ending\'
```

like in Cornholio's answer or you have to parse your `properties` file in a different way.

With the following command you will get variable INPUT (and others if there are more lines in `properties`) set to the correct value.

```
eval $(sed -e 's:[\!]:\\&:g' properties)
```

This will let the shell `eval`uate the output of the `sed` command which replaces `\` and `!` and in the contents of `properties`. The result will be variables with the original names `INPUT` etc. This will work if your `properties` file contains one or more variable assignments. It may give strange result with other shell script code.

**Note:** If your input file contains other special characters, the peprocessing would be more difficult. So using `eval` this way without additional checking may be fragile or dangerous.

With your example the variable `INPUT` will have the intended value `mark!slash\ending\`

After this you can do

```
SAFE_INPUT=$(printf '%s\n' "${INPUT}" | sed 's:[\!]:\\&:g')
```

if you need variable `SAVE_INPUT` to contain `mark\!slash\\ending\\`.

A better way would be to read the input line by line with `while read -r line` and check and process the line to separate variable name and value.

Comment: Preprocessing the script to run it through `eval` seems a bit fickly. At least you'd need to add backslashes in front of a bunch of other characters too, not just `!` and `\` (`$` would be an obvious one). Better to just quote the string in the original file.

Comment: im not sure quoting the string works, thats what im trying now, with apache configs.  things would actually be really messed up if you have to escapce every wierd character. your readfile would then look like a big regex escaped mess. So it almost seems counterintuitive that it would be possible by readfile, however there must be a way.  I need the readfile, when interepted by sed, to become the value of the variable, as opposed to literal `$var`.  e.g. it needs to eval, but i dont like restorting to an `eval()` solution either.Is that really our only option here?

Answer (score 1):

If I do the following, with the value of `INPUT` quoted, it works:

```
> INPUT='mark!slash\ending\'
> SAFE_INPUT=$(printf '%s\n' "${INPUT}" | sed 's:[\!]:\\&:g')
> echo $SAFE_INPUT
mark\!slash\\ending\\
```

Note, it's an exact copy of your script, with `INPUT=` added by me.

Comment: Hey, this is an answer that actually works, no need to even think about posting it as a comment instead of a proper answer!

Comment: This may work, but how would you then, use vars in your input string, which what im trying to do.  e.g. my input string is a file path, thats evaluated by sed read, as opposed to a var of data.  once sed read reads the text, i want the var evaluqated when read parses the read. Is this possible?